# http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php What does void mean?

Tags: php, mysql

You will notice that for prepared statements, the php.net list of functions is available at http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php even functions such as -> execute(); have the word *void* next to them what does this mean?

As I use many of these in my scripts, is it safe to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Void just means nothing is returned when the method has finished executing.

Answer (score 2):

`void` means "nothing" (in the meaning of the word). In PHP its equivalent to `null`. Usually you describe a return value with `void`, if the `return` expression in the method is completely omitted, whereas `null` as return value usually means

```
return null;
```

Note, that `void` is a pseudo-type in PHP. It doesnt exists in PHP and its only used in documetation to tell you, that there is really nothing (useful) returned.

Comment: Ah ok, I thought it meant something as not to use it! Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @Basic: Its similar ;) Because it always "returns" `null`, you can use it, but it wouldnt make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

From the [PHP Manual on Pseudo-Types and Variables](http://de.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.void):

> void as a return type means that the return value is useless. void in a parameter list means that the function doesn't accept any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Just like `bool` and `int`, `void` is a type. Placed beside a function declaration's name, it signifies that the function does not return anything. However, that does not mean the function does not perform any operations; it may have side effects, or it may execute other commands without passing anything back to the receiver.